# Unexpected result with work on js array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try delete excluded types from my object. And think in should work, but I don't understand, why 'company_accountant' still in the array.
And mayby you can help me and advice more elegant way to search and delete excluded types?

```
var data = [
    {id: 1, type: "exempt_dealer"},
    {id: 2, type: "licensed_dealer"},
    {id: 3, type: "partnership"},
    {id: 4, type: "company"},
    {id: 5, type: "licensed_dealer_accountant"},
    {id: 6, type: "company_accountant"},
    {id: 7, type: "partnership_accountant"}
];

var exclude_types = [
    'company_accountant',
    'licensed_dealer_accountant',
    'partnership_accountant'
];

angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
    if(exclude_types.includes(value.type)){
        data.splice(key, 1);
    }
});
```

**data** should be:

```
data = [
    {id: 1, type: "exempt_dealer"},
    {id: 2, type: "licensed_dealer"},
    {id: 3, type: "partnership"},
    {id: 4, type: "company"}
];
```

but for some reason:

```
{id: 1, type: "exempt_dealer"},
{id: 2, type: "licensed_dealer"},
{id: 3, type: "partnership"},
{id: 4, type: "company"},
{id: 6, type: "company_accountant"}
```

Comment: I don't know what `angular.forEach` does and why people don't just use `Array.prototype.forEach`, but it looks like you mutate your iterable while iterating, which is likely the cause of the problem (also the item before the one containing "company_accountant" is to be deleted, which matches that theory aswell).

Comment: Why aren't you using filter?

Comment: @ASDFGerte Yes, you're right about mutate - I don't deeply know js (@Luca ), and thats why try to use includes, because read aboun it in documentation. But about filter - I think, but dont't know how I can use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`splice` mutates the array during iteration. You should use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var data = [{id: 1, type: "exempt_dealer"},{id: 2, type: "licensed_dealer"},{id: 3, type: "partnership"},{id: 4, type: "company"},{id: 5, type: "licensed_dealer_accountant"},{id: 6, type: "company_accountant"},{id: 7, type: "partnership_accountant"}];
var exclude_types =['company_accountant','licensed_dealer_accountant','partnership_accountant'];

data = data.filter(({type}) => !exclude_types.includes(type));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks you, Nikhil! You was be first! And you give me the way to filter!

Comment: @InkyRein - Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

With the forEach method you take on the array one item at a time. When you are on item with id 5 you find it and delete it, so the item with id 6 takes it's place. Then the item with id 7 takes the item with id 6 place and so this is the next one checked and the other one is skipped. It is not considered a good idea to mutate the array you are looping through.
Using the array.filter method makes more sense:

```js
var data = [
    {id: 1, type: "exempt_dealer"},
    {id: 2, type: "licensed_dealer"},
    {id: 3, type: "partnership"},
    {id: 4, type: "company"},
    {id: 5, type: "licensed_dealer_accountant"},
    {id: 6, type: "company_accountant"},
    {id: 7, type: "partnership_accountant"}
];

var exclude_types = [
    'company_accountant',
    'licensed_dealer_accountant',
    'partnership_accountant'
];

var result = data.filter(item => !exclude_types.includes(item.type));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks Giannis for deeply explanation of my problem! Writing a solution is good, but here's why it's happening this is even better!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way to do achieve your desired result is to use the `Array.prototype.filter` method. In the callback function just check if the current element's `type` property is found in the `exclude_types` array:

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    type: "exempt_dealer"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: "licensed_dealer"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type: "partnership"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    type: "company"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    type: "licensed_dealer_accountant"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    type: "company_accountant"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    type: "partnership_accountant"
  }
];

var exclude_types = [
  'company_accountant',
  'licensed_dealer_accountant',
  'partnership_accountant'
];

var filtered = data.filter(function(el) {
  return exclude_types.indexOf(el.type) === -1;
});

console.log(filtered);
```